# With regex find and replace all require imports with ES import?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, requirejs, es6-modules

In VS Code I want to replace all my imports using require and update the import path...

`import myImport = require("path/of/import");`

to this

`import myImport from "path/of/import";`

Essentially...

Remove the `require(" ... ")` to replace with `from ""` syntax.

I've tried some tools and extensions in VS code, but they don't seem to work...so wanted to try just Regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but how about matching for the below:

```
import (\w+) = require\((.*?)\);?
```

… and replacing with the below:

```
import \1 from \2;
```

**Demo:**
https://regex101.com/r/gcVbPN/1

```js
const regex        = /import (\w+) = require\((.*?)\);?/;
const substitution = 'import $1 from $2;';

const before = 'import myImport = require("path/of/import");'
const after  = before.replace(regex, substitution);

console.log(`${before}\n${after}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to permanently change the import? As in, you now want your imports to be `import MyImport from "path/of/import";` and you don't need `import myImport = require("path/of/import");`? If so, you could likely use VS Code's Search tool (ctrl+shift+F), where you can search for a string of text and replace them across the entirety of the directory.

Comment: Yeah pretty much exactly that, but the problem I'm running into is the ) at the end. So I can get the first part done of `= require("` -> `from "` but the end of the requirejs statement `");` -> `";` is too broad to find. So made me think I need some more Regex to find like `= require("**");` -> `from "**";` where ** would be leave that part